# AutocompleteTextView not showing suggestions

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I've been trying to get an autocompletetextview to work but so far its not showing any results. Checked a lot of posts but couldnt get mine to work and i've tried every tutorial as well. Here is my code:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    autoCompleteAdapter = filler.execute(autoCompleteData).get();

                    inputEditText.setThreshold(5);
                    inputEditText.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
                    inputEditText.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
                    autoCompleteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    System.out.println("adapter obtained " + inputEditText.getAdapter());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

And this is the async task 'filer'

```
private class AutoCompleteFiller extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, String, ArrayAdapter<String>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayAdapter<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>[] autoCompleteData) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("wordcount.txt")));

            // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
            String mLine;
            while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                autoCompleteData[0].add(mLine);
            }
            String[] finalData = new String[autoCompleteData[0].size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < finalData.length; i++) {
                finalData[i] = autoCompleteData[0].get(i);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, finalData);
            System.out.println(autoCompleteData[0].size());
            return adapter;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //log the exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is the code which starts the thread:

```
t1.start();
```

Thank you.

Comment: So where do you set this adapter to your AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: There must be an Exception . You are accessing View in a non UI thread . See the logs . What is the use case of using `Thread` here ? you can simply call a method .

Comment: I dont think there is any exception cuz im using try catch and nothing is popping up in logcat. Im using a thread because the file im reading the suggestions from is big due to which the async task doesn't return that fast so i want all the suggestions to load before setting the adapter. And if i call get of async task on main thread it'll freeze everything

Comment: The adapter is setting correctly. It has all the data in it when i call the setadapter method. There is no exception in the log.

Comment: However, this is the only error i get:
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Comment: The thing is, i want to read suggestions from my own file.

Comment: You were right @ADM. I put the code where im setting the adapter and all after getting the result from the async task, in a runOnUi block and it worked. But what i don't get is why no exception was fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part where i was setting the adapter and all after getting the adapter from async task needed to be executed on the main thread. The answer was posted by ADM in the comments.